# When i printing through bat in windows 10, command running successfully but it didn't printed

Tags: batch-file, text, printing, windows-10

When I try to print in Windows 10 from a `.bat` file, the command appears to run successfully but nothing gets printed.

Here's my command, what am I doing wrong?

```
TYPE dir/filename >prn
```

Comment: can you please check with my below ans.

Comment: where it is please tell clear point?

Answer (score 0):

It's very, very easy in the Windows:

```
PRINT filename.txt /D:<printer_name>
```

Comment: PRINT filename.txt /D:<printer_name>

Comment: can you please try this one.

Comment: i will check and tell that command for newtork sharing printer is it correct what i am telling ?

Comment: get printer name by this ->  wmic printer get name /value | findstr Name